# undefined items from array in TypeScript for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular

When I'm setting an anonymous callback function on some REST service, I'm getting a very strange behavior where if I simply `console.log` the result of the REST service, I get the expected payload (an array of Objects). However, when I run a loop over the same array and try get some key's value, I get a error because apparently the item is `undefined`

```
...
callback: (result) => {
    console.log(result); // outputs [{text: 'foo'}, {text: 'bar'}]
    for(let item of result){
        console.log(item.text); // error can't read text of undefined
        console.log(item); // HOWEVER... this works... :/
    }
}
```

Any ideas? There must be some kind of async behavior happening, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a typescript error, this is just JavaScript

Comment: any idea why I get this error? Thanks

Comment: [Everything seems to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20result%20%3D%20%5B%7Btext%3A%20'foo'%7D%2C%20%7Btext%3A%20'bar'%7D%5D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(result)%3B%20%2F%2F%20outputs%20%5B%7Btext%3A%20'foo'%7D%2C%20%7Btext%3A%20'bar'%7D%5D%0D%0Afor(let%20item%20of%20result)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(item.text)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%20can't%20read%20text%20of%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(item)%3B%20%2F%2F%20HOWEVER...%20this%20works...%20%3A%2F%0D%0A%7D) as expected. Are you sure the `response` is really as in the comment?

Comment: use item['text'] instead of item.text. It should surely works...

Comment: Is this your actual code or you simplified it for the question? Have you debugged it using breakpoints?

Comment: This is a simplified version. Will try debugging and update post.

Comment: So please add your real code (or at least the problematic part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have a malformed array. Here is an example that demonstrates the problem:

```
// Malformed array
const result = [
    {text: 'foo'},
    {text: 'bar'},
]
result.length = 3;

// Your code
console.log(result); // outputs [{text: 'foo'}, {text: 'bar'}]
for(let item of result){
    console.log(item.text); // error can't read text of undefined
    console.log(item); // HOWEVER... this works... :/
}
```

## Fix

- Filter out the empty items.

## More tips

- console.log will print an empty line for unreasonable stuff. You might not be seeing that in your debugging
- Read up on JavaScript array holes
- Enjoy life

Comment: this is weird... and does not make much sense